# How long once I should change engine oil of my motorcycle

Tags: engine, oil-change

I am using unicorn 160cc bike.. Whenever I give the bike for service (4 months once) they change the engine oil.

But my friend change the engine oil of his bike every month and he is saying then only bike would be smooth to drive.

Is it so? What would be the interval to change the engine oil?

Comment: Once a month is incredibly excessive, and a huge waste of money and resources (unless he's hitting the milage suggested for change intervals, which I find hard to believe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the oil according to the service schedule provided by the manufacturer - there are exceptions for extreme / arduous use where the changes become more frequent but theses are also usually specified by the manufacturer.

Reducing the interval can make you happier, but too frequent - well it's your (his) money.

I used a very high quality (and very expensive) oil doubled the interval, but changed the filter twice as often which worked fine.

Comment: Thanks @solarmike.  I am driving around 50 kms per day. So, to know the interval,  as you said, I think it is  better checking the documents they provided along with the bike.